# Whats the Magento user registration observer

Tags: php, magento

I need to add customer verification system during registration.So when a user try to register in my site we send a sms to that he mentioned phone No. So here I need know what event will be triggered during registration (before success) ..?Please any one answer my question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **customer_save_before** observer event.

Also you can check if some of methods, such as save, load, delete supporting observer. For this you need open model class (example app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php) file and look for existing $_eventPrefix

If you open app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php file, you'll see something like this

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..!!  I just used customer_save_after observer event.